# R - C interface: extracting an object from an environment

Tags: c, r

Say that you pass an `environment` R object to an internal C routine through the `.Call` interface. Said `enviromnent` has (by design) a `someObject` object which I want to extract and manipulate from the C side. How to do it?

To simplify my question, I just want to write a C function that returns `someObject`. Like this:

```
en <- new.env()
en$someObject <- someValue
.Call("extractObject",en)
#the above should return en$someObject
```

Guess the C code should then look something like

```
SEXP extractObject(SEXP env) {
   return SOMEMACROORFUNCTION(env, "someObject");
}
```

Unfortunately, I was not able to find the real `SOMEMACROORFUNCTION`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little bit of googling and searching, I've found the solution:

```
findVar(install("someObject"),env)
```

in the C code is basically the equivalent of `get("someObject",env)` in R.